# Datos repetidos

Tags: laravel-5

Quisiera que me den una mano con esto ya que no encuentro la vuelta
Este seria mi código , La variable `$a` y `$b` las traigo del controlador y los valores son:

```
$a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$b=[1,4,8]
<select>
       @for ($i = 0; $i < count($b); $i++)
           @foreach ($a as $c)
                @if ($b[$i] == $c)
                    <option>{{ $c }}</option>
                @endif
           @endforeach
    @endfor
</select>
```

Con esta condición me trae un `select` `1,4,8` y si pongo esta condición  `!==` me trae del 2 al 10 después del 1 al 10 sin el 4 y por ultimo del 1 al 10 sin el 8.
Cómo tengo que hacer para que me traiga

> 2,3,5,6,7,9,10.

No se si es fácil o difícil pero no me doy cuenta como tengo que hacer.

Comment: Antes del for hay un select y donde aparece {{$c}} hay un option

Comment: ¿Cómo obtiene esos datos en el controlador ? , lo ideal sería realizar esta validación en el controlador y no en la plantilla `blade`. Sí `$b` contiene un valor que no está en `$a` ¿Debería mostrarlo también? , si no es así la respuesta de @Franklin sería la adecuada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer como esto:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$b = [1,4,8];
$resultado = array_diff($a, $b)

@foreach ($resultado as $value):
    {{$value}}
@endforeach
```

la envías a la vista la variable `$resultado`

Fuente: [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres obtener es la diferencia entre dos arreglos, para ello puedes usar la libreria underscore para hacerlo de manera mas simple y con menos lineas de codigo, ya que esta libreria aplica programacion funcional(sin estados de variables).

ejemplo:

```
$a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$b=[1,4,8]
__::difference($a, $b);
```

result:

```
 [2,3,5,6,7,9,10]
```

Referencia de la libreria en php https://brianhaveri.github.io/Underscore.php/

Esta misma libreria existe para javascript http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!